# Issue Unit Testing ASP .NET MVC 5 Project

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

When adding a Unit Test project to my solution in Visual Studio 2013, I got this error and the project is not created : 
"Class not registered. Looking for object with CLSID {1CACE4D9-C378-42BD-87DB-3C5D27334331}"

Does anyone know how I can fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: It might be the project is corrupted or invalid. Try repair VS and see if goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had to close solution and re-open and haven't had the problem since.